# jax rpc or jax ws by wsdl- how to know

Tags: java, web-services

Can I know from a `WSDL` in what specifiction a web service is written:
in `jax rpc` or `jax ws` ?

In my case web service is an entire service , can I be sure it is `jax rpc` and not `jax ws` ?

Is it possible to write a `jax ws client` to a `jax rpc service` ?

Answer (score 0):

A WSDL is simply a description of the web service interface, not the implementation. It may be jax rpc, jax ws, C#, or even written in assembler. You may as well ask what web server is responsible for serving a given HTML page.

That being said, there may be a [leaky abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction) at work. It is possible that one of the schemas or URLs has a "jax rpc" or "jax ws" in its name. There may be a comment in the WSDL with the implementation name. But there is nothing standard that specifies the implementation.

Comment: thank you . ok , I do see jax rpc in the wsdl urls . Can I implement a client with jax ws ?? if I am using some client wizard , will it dedicate the correct specification to use by the wsdl urls ?? how can someone know what specification to use only by the wsdl ?